# How can I use dynamic routes in nexy.js typescipt

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this folder structure

[image]

[postId].ts

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```

and I get this error and I don't know how to fix it, can someone tell me how to solve it?

[image]

upd:

Maybe the problem is in my tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what happen if you remove `{pid}` temporarily? Btw, you should be using `const { postId } = router.query`

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial nothing, I can leave just a text and it still doesn't work

Comment: You followed nextJS instructions to set up typescript? The codes you showed, at the very least, is not wrong (except for what I mentioned above)

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes I followed nextjs docs

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it probably has to be something with typescript

Answer (score 0):

You file name is `[postId]`, so should be your param name:

```
const { postId } = router.query
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-browser-hvhn4?file=/pages/posts/%5Bposts%5D.js

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should be a jsx / tsx type so

instead of

```
[postId].ts
```

Should be

```
[postId].tsx
```

Answer (score -1):

I just went from webstorm to vscode and everything works fine, maybe it was a problem in my tsconfig file